# Como puedo cambiar que en ves de que muestre un menu , solo me muestre otro layout

Tags: android-studio, android-intent

Cargo el menú el de `onCreateMenu` que contiene en un `ListView` son unos *contactos telefónicos*, que al presionar en ellos(Item) me lleven a una `activity` llamada Detalles.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageButton floatButton;
    private AmigoAdapter adapter;

    public static ArrayList<Amigo> listaAmigos = new ArrayList<Amigo>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lvAmigos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvAmigos);
        adapter = new AmigoAdapter(this,MainActivity.listaAmigos);
        lvAmigos.setAdapter(adapter);

        registerForContextMenu(lvAmigos);

        floatButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btRegistro);
        floatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        ImageButton btRegistro = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btRegistro);
        btRegistro.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_listado, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_registrar:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registro.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_context_listado, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
                (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        final int itemSeleccionado = info.position;
        Amigo amigo = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_fijo:
                amigo = MainActivity.listaAmigos.get(itemSeleccionado);
                String telefonoFijo = amigo.getTelefonoFijo();
                Intent intentLlamada = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intentLlamada.setData(Uri.parse("tel: " + telefonoFijo));
                startActivity(intentLlamada);
                break;
            case R.id.action_movil:
                amigo = MainActivity.listaAmigos.get(itemSeleccionado);
                String telefonoMovil = amigo.getTelefonoMovil();
                Intent intentMovil = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intentMovil.setData(Uri.parse("tel: " + telefonoMovil));
                startActivity(intentMovil);
                break;
            case R.id.action_editar:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registro.class);
                intent.putExtra("posicion", itemSeleccionado);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.action_eliminar:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.lb_esta_seguro)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.lb_si,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        MainActivity.listaAmigos.remove(itemSeleccionado);
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.lb_eliminado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.lb_no,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                builder.create().show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_email:
                amigo = MainActivity.listaAmigos.get(itemSeleccionado);
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, amigo.getEmail());
                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.selecciona_email)));
                break;
            case R.id.action_detalles:
                Intent intentDetalles = new Intent(this, Detalles.class);
                intentDetalles.putExtra("posicion", itemSeleccionado);
                startActivity(intentDetalles);

                Notification.Builder nBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay)
                        .setContentTitle("Prueba")
                        .setContentText("Esto es una notificacion");
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                manager.notify(0, nBuilder.build());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
/*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
*/
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btRegistro:
                // El usuario ha pulsado el botón de Registro. Se lanza la Activity para registrar un nuevo Amigo
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Registro.class));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

    introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: En que parte estas cargando el menu que mencionas? Te refieres al que infla onCreateOptionsMenu o alguno que se carga mediante setContentView?

Comment: si el de onCreateMenu estan en un ListView son unos contactos telefonicos quiero que al precionar en ellos me lleven a una activity llamada Detalles

Comment: Quieres que dentro de un listview al hacer click en alguno de los item te derive a otra actividad? no entiendo bien mm

Comment: si eso es como los contactos de tu cel solo le das clik a uno de ellos y te lleva a ver los detalles

Comment: el mio lo hace pero atraves de un menu debes sostener para que el te salga y luego elegis la opcion y no quiero eso quiero que solo un click y te mande a detalles .. lo hice pero solo me manda a la activity no con los datos correspondientes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes crear una actividad nueva, y dentro de su recpetivo XML añadir un `Lisview`, cargar tus contactos en el adaptador y con la función :

```
miLista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(position ==0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(actividad1.this,actividad2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (position==1){
                Intent intent = new Intent(actividad4.this,actividad5.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if(position==2){
                Intent intent = new Intent(actividad6.this,actividad7.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
 }
 });
```

Te ayudara para cada vez que presiones un **item** te derive a otra actividad en este caso.
Debes  ir sumándole uno mas a cada posición no olvides ese detalle.

Comment: gracias Ashley tratare de hacer lo que me has dicho

Comment: @alvin he editado mi respuesta, así debes hacerlo en el método setOnItemClickListener, solo debes cambiar los nombres de tu actividades obviamente

Comment: gracias me has ayudado en bastante te lo agradezco

Comment: @alvin, me alegro haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: si claro que si .. fue un gusto vale!

Comment: @alvin recuerda en dar por aceptada la respuesta, para que se cierre la pregunta. cuando site +1 abajo esta la opcion, en el check :D

Answer (score -1):

La unica forma de hacer eso es editar tu menu

```
/res/menu
```

Como no muestras la parte xml de tu menú, me supongo que es algo así.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Entonces que es lo que hay que modificar?, pues es el atributo

```
showAsAction=”never”
```

de forma que ésta siempre aparezca en el menú de overflow.

Te dejo un ejemplo de un menu que tengo.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Detalles.ActivityEmpleadoDetalles">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Opc1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pencil"
        android:iconTint="@color/bg_login"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_ed"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Opc2"
        android:icon="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
        android:iconTint="@color/bg_login"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
        android:iconTint="@color/bg_login"
        android:title="Opc3"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Y entonces que fue lo se hizo para modificar la forma de visualizar ese menú, te dejo una descripción de los diferentes atributos que puedes agregar al menu.

> **android:id**. El ID identificativo del elemento, con el que podremos
>   hacer referencia dicha opción.
>
> **android:title**. El texto que se visualizará para la opción.
>
> **android:icon**. El icono asociado a la acción.
>
> > **android:showAsAction**. Si se está mostrando una action bar, este atributo indica si la opción de menú se mostrará como botón de acción
> >     o como parte del menú de overflow. Puede tomar varios valores:
> >
> > > **ifRoom**. Se mostrará como botón de acción sólo si hay espacio disponible.
> > >
> > > **withText**. Se mostrará el texto de la opción junto al icono en el caso de que éste se esté mostrando como botón de acción.
> > >        never. La opción siempre se mostrará como parte del menú de overflow.
> > >
> > > **always**. La opción siempre se mostrará como botón de acción. Este valor puede provocar que los elementos se solapen si no hay espacio suficiente para ellos.

Dando como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que no era lo que el pedia mmm creo que lo que desea es hacer click en el item y que lo derive a una actividad nueva llamda detalle ...

Comment: gracias te entiendo solo lo que pues queria era que al dar un clik al contacto guardado me mandara a la activity de detalle pero con sus datos correspondientes .. hasta ahora me sale un menu el cual me da opciones de ir a una infinidad de opciones en ella el de detalle pero no lo kiero asi

Comment: si eso Ashley  eso es lo que necesito